# Find Max Values of Elements in Nested Object Inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a multidimensional array that looks like:

```
[ { j: 15, temps: 33.55, pressureVal: 1021, cloudCover: 95 },
  { j: 16, temps: 34.05, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 98 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.14, pressureVal: 1018, cloudCover: 99 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.16, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 100 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.68, pressureVal: 1014, cloudCover: 100 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32, pressureVal: 1015, cloudCover: 99 },
  { j: 16, temps: 33.53, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 92 },
  { j: 16, temps: 37.06, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 89 },
  { j: 16, temps: 37.69, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 48 },
  { j: 17, temps: 34.86, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 71 },
  { j: 17, temps: 33.78, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 60 },
  { j: 17, temps: 33.53, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 57 },
  { j: 17, temps: 32.45, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 14 },
  { j: 17, temps: 32.61, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 26 },
  { j: 17, temps: 36.5, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 93 },
  { j: 17, temps: 39.13, pressureVal: 1018, cloudCover: 97 },
  { j: 17, temps: 39.74, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 100 } ]
```

I need to find the max value of temps, pressureVal and cloudCover for each different j value.  Any ideas how to work with this type of data structure?

Comment: look into `Math.max()`, the spread operator, and `array.map`. If you encounter specific issues, feel free to post back here; otherwise, stackoverflow isn't a 'do x for me' type forum.

Comment: is your data sorted? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through all of the items and compare it to another set of items that keeps track of the max values.

```js
let items = [ { j: 15, temps: 33.55, pressureVal: 1021, cloudCover: 95 },
  { j: 16, temps: 34.05, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 98 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.14, pressureVal: 1018, cloudCover: 99 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.16, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 100 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32.68, pressureVal: 1014, cloudCover: 100 },
  { j: 16, temps: 32, pressureVal: 1015, cloudCover: 99 },
  { j: 16, temps: 33.53, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 92 },
  { j: 16, temps: 37.06, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 89 },
  { j: 16, temps: 37.69, pressureVal: 1016, cloudCover: 48 },
  { j: 17, temps: 34.86, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 71 },
  { j: 17, temps: 33.78, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 60 },
  { j: 17, temps: 33.53, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 57 },
  { j: 17, temps: 32.45, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 14 },
  { j: 17, temps: 32.61, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 26 },
  { j: 17, temps: 36.5, pressureVal: 1019, cloudCover: 93 },
  { j: 17, temps: 39.13, pressureVal: 1018, cloudCover: 97 },
  { j: 17, temps: 39.74, pressureVal: 1017, cloudCover: 100 } ]
let maxValues = []

for (const item of items) {
   let maxItem = maxValues.find(v => v.j === item.j)
   if (!maxItem) {
     maxItem = { j: item.j }
     maxValues.push(maxItem)
   }
   if (!maxItem.temps || item.temps > maxItem.temps)
     maxItem.temps = item.temps
   if (!maxItem.pressureVal || item.pressureVal > maxItem.pressureVal)
     maxItem.pressureVal = item.pressureVal
   if (!maxItem.cloudCover || item.cloudCover > maxItem.cloudCover)
     maxItem.cloudCover = item.cloudCover
}
console.log(maxValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` and at the same time group by `j` property and also get the maximum values of other properties by checking current element value and accumulator value for the same key.

```js
const data = [{"j":15,"temps":33.55,"pressureVal":1021,"cloudCover":95},{"j":16,"temps":34.05,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":98},{"j":16,"temps":32.14,"pressureVal":1018,"cloudCover":99},{"j":16,"temps":32.16,"pressureVal":1016,"cloudCover":100},{"j":16,"temps":32.68,"pressureVal":1014,"cloudCover":100},{"j":16,"temps":32,"pressureVal":1015,"cloudCover":99},{"j":16,"temps":33.53,"pressureVal":1016,"cloudCover":92},{"j":16,"temps":37.06,"pressureVal":1017,"cloudCover":89},{"j":16,"temps":37.69,"pressureVal":1016,"cloudCover":48},{"j":17,"temps":34.86,"pressureVal":1017,"cloudCover":71},{"j":17,"temps":33.78,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":60},{"j":17,"temps":33.53,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":57},{"j":17,"temps":32.45,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":14},{"j":17,"temps":32.61,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":26},{"j":17,"temps":36.5,"pressureVal":1019,"cloudCover":93},{"j":17,"temps":39.13,"pressureVal":1018,"cloudCover":97},{"j":17,"temps":39.74,"pressureVal":1017,"cloudCover":100}]

const result = data.reduce((r, { j , ...rest }) => {
  if (!r[j]) r[j] = { ...rest }
  else {
    for (let i in rest) {
      if (rest[i] > r[j][i]) {
        r[j][i] = rest[i]
      }
    }
  }

  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```